# 5x5x5 Tic Tac Toe status

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

According to: 
http://library.msri.org/books/Book42/files/golomb.pdf from 2002,
It is conjectured that in 5x5x5 Tic Tac Toe (standard rules), the second player ('O') can force a draw in a perfect play.

Are there any updates since then?

Also, are there any updates on 4x4x4x4x4, where it is conjectured that the first player ('X') has an easy win?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does one actually play $5\times 5\times 5\times 5$ Tic-Tac-Toe? By storing a $5\times 5\times 5\times 5$ array on a computer and updating it according to the player's moves?

Comment: From that paper: "Surely this constitutes “proof beyond a
reasonable doubt”, and would almost certainly convince not only a jury, but an
engineer, a statistician, even a physicist, but (we hope) not a true mathematician.
Because this purported “identity” is not always true!" - Haha!

Comment: @Math1000 - Thanks allot for your comments. Maybe I misunderstood you, but 1: I asked about 5x5x5 not 5x5x5x5. 2: Actual play is not necessary to have mathematical proofs about an object. 3: Your quote does not refer to the issues I raised

Comment: Oh, I typed an extra $5$. And yes, actual play is not necessary to have mathematical proofs of an object, but it is still of interest.